# Jetty 8: proxyservlet use ExecutorThreadPool or QueuedThreadPool

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

I'm using Jetty 8 with its ProxyServlet, and was wondering what's the fastest threadpool to use, ExecutorThreadPool or QueuedThreadPool?

This is the code I'm currently using:

```java
  Server httpProxy = new Server();
  SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
  connector.setPort(8087);
  connector.setMaxIdleTime(400000);
  connector.setThreadPool(new ExecutorThreadPool(256));
  httpProxy.addConnector(connector);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our tests, `QueuedThreadPool` has shown to be faster than `ExecutorThreadPool` for usage with a connector.

I would use `QueuedThreadPool` and experiment with `ExecutorThreadPool` only if you have performance problems caused by the thread pool (unlikely in our experience).